# Transpose complex data.frame with tidyR

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have an example data.frame that looks like this:

```
rep = c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
day = c(0,0,0,1,1,1)
trt1= c(10,10,20,10,10,20) 
trt2=c(10,10,20,10,10,20) 
trt3 = c(10,10,20,10,10,20) 
exam = data.frame(rep,day,trt1,trt2,trt3)
exam

 rep   day trt1 trt2 trt3
1   1   0   10   10   10
2   2   0   10   10   10
3   3   0   20   20   20
4   1   1   10   10   10
5   2   1   10   10   10
6   3   1   20   20   20
```

I would like to use tidyR to bring it in this form

```
rep  Treatments  0   1   
1        trt1    10  10   
1        trt2    10  10
1        trt3    10  10
2        trt1    10  10
2        trt2    10  10
2        trt3    10  10
```

where I mainly bring the days as columns

Any help or direction are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- exam %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(1,2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = day,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
    rep name    `0`   `1`
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 trt1     10    10
2     1 trt2     10    10
3     1 trt3     10    10
4     2 trt1     10    10
5     2 trt2     10    10
6     2 trt3     10    10
7     3 trt1     20    20
8     3 trt2     20    20
9     3 trt3     20    20
```

Comment: You are so fast :) Then I have to use `data.table`, haha. Liked your answer!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Just a bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option with `dcast` + `melt`

```
> dcast(melt(setDT(exam), id = 1:2), rep + variable ~ day)
   rep variable  0  1
1:   1     trt1 10 10
2:   1     trt2 10 10
3:   1     trt3 10 10
4:   2     trt1 10 10
5:   2     trt2 10 10
6:   2     trt3 10 10
7:   3     trt1 20 20
8:   3     trt2 20 20
9:   3     trt3 20 20
```